# Why isn't my datagrid updating the DB? WPF .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-4.5

I am trying to bind a database table to a datagrid view. I only want to show certain fields, omitting user-irrelevant fields such as ID, CREATED_BY, CREATED_ON, etc. I can load the list correctly, but updating back to the DB doesn't work.

EDITED - CLEANED CODE A BIT.

This is what I have to load the data grid view.
XAML:

```
<Grid Margin="0">
    <DataGrid x:Name="ProductsDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Style="{StaticResource AzureDataGrid}" Background="White" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" Margin="0,0,0,50" RenderTransformOrigin="0.479,0.06">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"  Binding="{Binding FP1_NAME}" Width="Auto"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn ElementStyle="{DynamicResource MetroDataGridCheckBox}"
                EditingElementStyle="{DynamicResource MetroDataGridCheckBox}"
                Header="Is Needed"
                            />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button x:Name="ProductsGridUpdate" Content="update" Style="{StaticResource AccentedSquareButtonStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="424,280,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" RenderTransformOrigin="1.453,1.103" Click="ProductsGridUpdate_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

and here is the code behind:

```
private void LoadList()
    {
        //init
        ProductsDataGrid.Items.Clear();
        ProductsDataGrid.BeginInit();
        ProductsDataGrid.ItemsSource = SQLCommands.GR1_DataSet.fp1_food_products;
        ProductsDataGrid.DataContext = SQLCommands.GR1_DataSet.fp1_food_products;
        ProductsDataGrid.EndInit();
    }
#endregion

private void ProductsGridUpdate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ // this does not work? No error is thrown, and it runs. DB just doesn't update. 
    SQLCommands.fp1_adapter.Update (SQLCommands.GR1_DataSet.fp1_food_products);
}
```

Here is what I run at app startup to prepare for loading the list:

```
public static void SQLFoodProductsProvider()
{
    GR1_DataSet = new GroceryListDataSet();

    fp1_adapter = new GroceryListDataSetTableAdapters.fp1_food_productsTableAdapter();
    fp1_adapter.Fill(GR1_DataSet.fp1_food_products);


    //GR1_DataSet.fp1_food_products.fp1_food_productsRowChanged +=
    //    new GroceryListDataSet.fp1_food_productsRowChangeEventHandler(MainWindow.fp1_food_productsRowModified);
    //GR1_DataSet.fp1_food_products.fp1_food_productsRowDeleted +=
    //    new GroceryListDataSet.fp1_food_productsRowChangeEventHandler(MainWindow.fp1_food_productsRowModified);
}
```

Any help or direction is much appreciated. Thank you in advance. I created the db using Visual Studio if that matters.

Comment: uncommenting ProductsDataGrid.DataContext = data; gets rid of the exception, but then the db still does not update.

Comment: Have you debugged to check whether the DataTable has anything in it?

Comment: I changed the code to follow some other tutorials a bit more, and make it a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. I've officially prematurely gone bald, but I've figured it out. On the DB object, there is a property, 'Copy to output directory'.

By default it was set to `'Always Copy'`. Setting it to `'Copy if newer'` fixed ALL my issues.

Will leave up because out of all of the StackOverflow posts ( among other sites ), I've yet to see this as a possible solution.